# KEY MAPPING (v2.8) ~ Is there any way to remap the Y axis hotkey to `C` for a more practical use?

Tags: shortcut, axis

MY ISSUE: I use the `Z/X/Y` axis shortcuts a lot when modeling, rather than visualizing the transformation gizmo.
I'd like to have the three shortcuts in a single row of three consecutive keys.

Having to travel halfway over the keyboard each time the Y axis is involved is a bit stressing (especially when I have to exclude it, `Shift+Y`!!) and it'd be great if I could just tap no further than one key to the right of the `X`.

Obviously I could just redirect the `Y` key to `C` with AutoHotKey, but then I'd have to swap `C` to `Y` and move there every time I need to "paint select".

I need a conditional key remapping that allows me to use the `C` key to pick the Y axis every time move/scale/rotation are the active mode.
While retaining the `C` key paint selection shortcut, of course.

I've briefly tried to dive into the key mapping setup of Blender 2.8, but it looks kinda complex and very script dependent.
Probably there is a way to do what I want through the UI rather than by script, but I couldnt see any key binding for the Y axis shortcut and I cant really understand how to add one.

In case scripting is the only way, I'd use a link to a tut on how to make/implement scritps and the script itself.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, it seems I just needed to say it out loud to actually guess the solution.
Here it is:

.- [menu] `Edit` -> [entry] `Preferences...`
-. [section] `Keymap`
.- [search filter] filter by `Key-Binding` (rather than by `Name`)
-. [search field] enter: Y
.- look for `Y axis` and `Y plane`

Then just click on the key binding button (first to last in the row) and press the key you need (`C` and `Shift+C` in my case).