# The "period key" next to the zero not there on a laptop

Tags: shortcut

A great key, but how to strike it without a number keypad on a laptop. An external number keypad not an option.

Comment: You can always remap your keys to whatever you like, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139047/key-mapping-v2-8-is-there-any-way-to-remap-the-y-axis-hotkey-to-c-for-a-mo

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the key is called- maybe the Accent key?  Followed by #3.  See below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for, the "view" key being I hadn't thought in that way.